# Openness and differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-topology

Given that $A$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^n$ and $f:A \to \mathbb R^n$ is differentiable, and its derivative is non-singular at every point in $A$, prove that $f(A)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$

Note $f$ is differentiable, *not* continuously differentiable.

Comment: Note that the tag "open-problem" is for problems for which no solution is known, *not* for problems concerning open sets.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is given in this excellent post by Terence Tao

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/

Answer (score 1):

By the inverse function theorem  for each $x\in A$ there exists open sets $x\in U$ and $f(x)\in V$ so that  $f|_U:U\to V$  is a  diffeomorphism. So in particular $f(U)=V$ hence $f(x)\in V\subset f(A)$.

Comment: But $f$ was *not* assumed to be continuously differentiable which is needed in the usual proof of the inverse function theorem via the Banach fixed point theorem.